# SQL Server + triggers: How to get information about the inserted/deleted tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Is there any way to get information about the updated/deleted tables in a trigger, meaning

- which columns are in the inserted/deleted tables?
- which data types do they have?

The background for this question is: I would like to create a 'generic' trigger which can be used without having need to be adapted for the table in question.

Dummy code:

- foreach column in inserted table
- get column name and data type and column (e.g. to exclude text columns or columns with a special name)
- if the value has changed do some logging into another table

Unfortunately I could not find the needed information so far; I have to admit that I don't know the proper key words which have to be used.

It would even be helpful to get a list of functions (e.g. UPDATE()) which can be used in triggers to query information about the inserted/deleted tables.

The TSQL code should work on MS SQL Server >= 2008.

TIA

Comment: Instead of a trigger you could use Change Data Capture (CDC) to capture changes to data in tables. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645937.aspx and https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Instead of a trigger, you could use merge statements to do the table updating, and output the actions the merge performed into your logging table: see these msdn articles: [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx) and [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: There is no way a "generic" trigger is going to work. A trigger is created as an event handler on a given table and must be written for that table. CDC is much better than a roll your own trigger implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions; I'm gonna give it a try.